# why admob not showing any ads in test device

Tags: android

i am new in android  and i have created one apps and want to include admob ad to it.
my manifest file is:

```
<!-- Include required permissions for Google Mobile Ads to run-->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


<meta-data android:name="ADMOB_PUBLISHER_ID"
        android:value="pub-1205981486869590" />


<!--Include the AdActivity configChanges and theme. -->
        <activity android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent" />
```

Main.java------------

```
AdView adView = new AdView(this);
    adView.setAdUnitId("ca-app-pub-1205981486869590/1687879061 ");
    adView.setAdSize(AdSize.BANNER);

    //LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.adView);
    //layout.addView(adView);



    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder()
    .addTestDevice("4d08da7768519000")

    .build();

    adView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

i dont know what i am missing or doing wrong....it is not showing ad plz help me

Comment: What do use see in logs?

Comment: how do you add AdView into your layout ?

Comment: please post Your layout xml. You have to ad the AdView inside the layout

Comment: These line   added in layout         <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/adView"
                           android:layout_width="match_parent"
                           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                           ads:adSize="BANNER"
                           ads:adUnitId=""

                           />

Answer (score 0):

You have to configure your layout try to add this

```
 <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
```

If you want to have more information you can check the official documentation: [Admob - get started](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start)